# MySQL: AVG Difference of 2 Columns in Different Rows Based on Value in 3rd Column (Separate Tables)

Tags: mysql

I need to find:

AVG(S1.CLS - S3.OPN) of every row where SIGNAL = 3.

(S1 means when SIGNAL = 1, and S3 means when SIGNAL = 3, I assume these will become derived tables somehow?)

**REQUIREMENTS:**

- The 'S1.CLS' must be the nearest/smallest row/id after the row with 'S3.OPN'. ie-
  MIN(S1.ID) > S3.ID
- S1.YRWK = S3.YRWK

My Data is coming together via a Derived Tabled of Joins from 3 separate tables.

**SAMPLE DATA:**

| ID | DT | YRWK | OPN | CLS | SIGNAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | 9/6/2005 18:16 | 200536 | 1138.5 | 1138.5 | 3 |
| 216 | 9/6/2005 21:25 | 200536 | 1137.75 | 1138 | 3 |
| 230 | 9/6/2005 21:53 | 200536 | 1137.5 | 1137.5 | 1 |
| 290 | 9/7/2005 0:20 | 200536 | 1138.25 | 1138.5 | 3 |
| 299 | 9/7/2005 0:32 | 200536 | 1138.25 | 1138.25 | 1 |
| 315 | 9/7/2005 1:02 | 200536 | 1138.5 | 1138.5 | 3 |
| 318 | 9/7/2005 1:05 | 200536 | 1138.5 | 1138.25 | 1 |
| 320 | 9/7/2005 1:07 | 200536 | 1138 | 1137.75 | 1 |
| 322 | 9/7/2005 1:09 | 200536 | 1138 | 1137.75 | 1 |
| 325 | 9/7/2005 1:12 | 200536 | 1138.25 | 1138.25 | 3 |
| 338 | 9/7/2005 1:25 | 200536 | 1138.5 | 1138.25 | 1 |
| 362 | 9/7/2005 1:53 | 200536 | 1138 | 1138.25 | 3 |
| 365 | 9/7/2005 1:57 | 200536 | 1137.75 | 1137.75 | 1 |
| 374 | 9/7/2005 2:08 | 200536 | 1138 | 1138.25 | 3 |
| 376 | 9/7/2005 2:10 | 200536 | 1138.25 | 1138.5 | 3 |
| 406 | 9/7/2005 2:42 | 200536 | 1138 | 1138 | 3 |

**EXPECTED ANSWER**
(ID= 124, CLS= 1138.5) - ( ID= 230, OPN= 1137.5),

(ID= 216, CLS= 1138) - ( ID= 230, OPN= 1137.5),

(ID= 290, CLS= 1138.5) - (ID= 299, OPN= 1138.25),

**(ID= 315, CLS= 1138.5) - (ID= 318, OPN= 1138.5)**

And then take all those differences and Average them together.

**NOTE** - The last row- notice how it takes OPN from row 318, and NOT rows 320 or 322

Thank you!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Didn't I provide this in the original above?
I've tried many different ways to do this- from creating a separate temporary table, multiple tables, subqueries, etc etc. Nothing works. Seems to me the biggest challenge is crossing over and using the criteria of MIN(S1.ID) > S3.ID WHERE Signal = 3. I'm at a loss on how to do this. Can you help?

Comment: No. Unfortunately, experience tells us that from this point, this rarely goes well.